# changing the laucher2 package name android

Tags: android, launcher

I am trying to implement my own launcher (making some modifications to the launcher provided by google ). But since i cant remove the default launcher i renamed my package name and everything . Initially the package name was com.android.launcher2 . I changed every instance it to com.rohit.grid . Now if I run it i am getting this error **'Re-installation failed due to different application signatures'** .Now the manifest file has some something called com.android.launcher in the permission tags & in the packge name . If i replace it with com.rohit.grid I will get errors in xml files about some resource being not resolved.

I tried cleanoing the project, fixing its properties & everything . But it dint help .

Somebody plz get me out of this problem .

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rohit

Comment: can you show your manifest file.

Comment: i have put my manifest file . let me know if there are any mistakes

Comment: have you tried uninstalling and then reinstalling the app

Comment: it does not get installed in the first place & I cant remove the default launcher

Comment: i dont think you need to redefine permissions, they are already defined in Launcher. Remove all items with permission tag

Comment: but permissions should be there right

Answer (score 0):

I think **'Re-installation failed due to different application signatures'** means that the installer is trying to install an APK with the same name that an installed one, but the problem in this case is that the installed is signed with a different key than yours.

Instead of modifying your manifest try to rename the project and then reinstall.

Comment: Your manifest **must** declare a different package name. If you get errors, fix those errors, you will not be able to install your app alongside the existing launcher app if they both declare the same package name.